# Python pyautogui loop with scrollIntoView becomes stale

Tags: python, selenium, pyautogui, staleelementreferenceexception

I have a python script that's almost working but there is a problem that I cannot resolve. My loop is working but only for the first row of images. For some reason the webelement becomes stale after 3 images. I'm positive that there are more than 3 html elements that match my query though! I'm using this script to bring the elements into view `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", i)`. Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# from selenium.webdriver.chrome import options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import time
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import pyautogui

# driver_path = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path)
options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("https://superrare.com/market?market-options=%257B%2522first%2522%3A30%2C%2522orderBy%2522%3A%2522RECENT_NFT_EVENT_BY_TOKEN_CONTRACT_ADDRESS_AND_TOKEN_ID__TIMESTAMP_DESC%2522%2C%2522fileTypes%2522%3A%255B%2522image%2Fjpeg%2522%2C%2522image%2Fpng%2522%255D%2C%2522listPrice%2522%3Afalse%2C%2522isGenesis%2522%3Afalse%2C%2522isSeries%2522%3Afalse%2C%2522neverReceivedOffer%2522%3Afalse%2C%2522reservePrice%2522%3Afalse%2C%2522liveAuctions%2522%3Afalse%2C%2522upcomingAuctions%2522%3Afalse%2C%2522hasSold%2522%3Afalse%2C%2522ownedByCreator%2522%3Afalse%2C%2522openOffers%2522%3Afalse%2C%2522artistsCollected%2522%3Afalse%2C%2522artistsYouFollow%2522%3Afalse%2C%2522artistsThatFollowYou%2522%3Afalse%2C%2522artistsFollowedByFollowed%2522%3Afalse%2C%2522lowerPriceRange%2522%3A0%2C%2522upperPriceRange%2522%3A100000%2C%2522numCreatorSales%2522%3Afalse%2C%2522lowerMintedRange%2522%3Anull%2C%2522upperMintedRange%2522%3Anull%2C%2522startCursor%2522%3A%2522WyJyZWNlbnRfbmZ0X2V2ZW50X2J5X3Rva2VuX2NvbnRyYWN0X2FkZHJlc3NfYW5kX3Rva2VuX2lkX190aW1lc3RhbXBfZGVzYyIsWyIyMDIyLTAxLTE5VDAxOjA3OjAxKzAwOjAwIiwiMHg0MWEzMjJiMjhkMGZmMzU0MDQwZTJjYmM2NzZmMDMyMGQ4Yzg4NTBkIiwxNDQxXV0%3D%2522%2C%2522endCursor%2522%3A%2522WyJyZWNlbnRfbmZ0X2V2ZW50X2J5X3Rva2VuX2NvbnRyYWN0X2FkZHJlc3NfYW5kX3Rva2VuX2lkX190aW1lc3RhbXBfZGVzYyIsWyIyMDIyLTAxLTE4VDEyOjEzOjMzKzAwOjAwIiwiMHhiOTMyYTcwYTU3NjczZDg5ZjRhY2ZmYmU4MzBlOGVkN2Y3NWZiOWUwIiwzMTY4OV1d%2522%2C%2522hasPreviousPage%2522%3Afalse%2C%2522hasNextPage%2522%3Atrue%257D")
actions = ActionChains(driver)

time.sleep(3)

ele=driver.find_element("xpath", '//div[@id="root"]')

total_height = ele.size["height"]
time.sleep(2)  

driver.set_window_size(1920, total_height)
time.sleep(2)



downloadimg = WebDriverWait(driver,50).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//section[contains(@class,'md-media')]")))

for i in downloadimg:
    # bring the webelement into the viewport
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", i)
    downloadimg2 = WebDriverWait(driver,50).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//img[contains(@class,'new-grid-img')]")))
    for img in downloadimg2:
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", img)
        time.sleep(2)
        # determine element's location; the +190 and -100 is to make the mouse show ON the element rather than at it's border
        location = img.location 
        size = img.size 
        x = location['x']+190
        y = location['y']-100   
        # move to the element 
        pyautogui.moveTo((int(x), int(y)), duration=2)
        time.sleep(2)
        # right click
        actions.context_click(img).perform()
        # move to open in new browser tab
        pyautogui.move(0, -25, duration=1)
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.click()
        # move to the new browser tab and click 
        pyautogui.moveTo(480, 50, duration=2)
        pyautogui.click()
        # give time to the img to load
        time.sleep(4)
        # move to the image and click
        pyautogui.moveTo(780, 550, duration=2)
        pyautogui.click()
        # actions.context_click(i).perform()
        # right click and mobe to save img as and then click
        pyautogui.rightClick()
        pyautogui.move(20, 200, duration=2)
        pyautogui.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        # press enter in the dialog box to actually save the img to download folder
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        time.sleep(2)
        # close the tab and go back to the beginning of the loop
        pyautogui.hotkey('command', 'w')
```

Comment: just removed a "while true" line that wasn't doing anything... I think!

Answer (score 0):

This specific web site is not initially loading all the images.
So, when you are scrolling to the images in the second row only then this images are being loaded. This causes the web elements changes so that the initial list of pictures `downloadimg` becomes no more relevant, in Selenium terms Stale Elements.
To make your code working you will need to get the `downloadimg` list again after each scrolling, something like this:

```py
downloadimg = WebDriverWait(driver,50).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//img[contains(@class,'new-grid-img')]")))


for i in downloadimg:
    # bring the webelement into the viewport
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", i)
    downloadimg = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('img.new-grid-img')
    time.sleep(2)
    # determine element's location; the +190 and -100 is to make the mouse show ON the element rather than at it's border
    location = i.location 
    size = i.size 
    x = location['x']+190
    y = location['y']-100   
    # move to the element 
    pyautogui.moveTo((int(x), int(y)), duration=2)
    time.sleep(2)
    # right click
    actions.context_click(i).perform()
    # move to open in new browser tab
    pyautogui.move(0, -25, duration=1)
    time.sleep(1)
    pyautogui.click()
    # move to the new browser tab and click 
    pyautogui.moveTo(480, 50, duration=2)
    pyautogui.click()
    # give time to the img to load
    time.sleep(4)
    # move to the image and click
    pyautogui.moveTo(780, 550, duration=2)
    pyautogui.click()
    # actions.context_click(i).perform()
    # right click and mobe to save img as and then click
    pyautogui.rightClick()
    pyautogui.move(20, 200, duration=2)
    pyautogui.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    # press enter in the dialog box to actually save the img to download folder
    pyautogui.press('enter')
    time.sleep(2)
    # close the tab and go back to the beginning of the loop
    pyautogui.hotkey('command', 'w')
```

You should remove the redundant `driver.quit()` from your code as well

Comment: Thx @Prophet. I will give this a try. I had thought about something like that but was not sure how to implement within the loop. Your line <downloadimg = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('img.new-grid-img')> re-creates the object but then the rest of the loop refers back to "i". Any further thoughts about integrating this to the loop?

Comment: Yes, this will re-create / update the `downloadimg` list of elements without reference to `i` so you will continue with your loop. What else do you need here? In case you will have any problems - please let me know

Comment: hi again @Prophet. I tried and tried but I'm not finding a solution yet. Your suggestion was not integrating the loop. The second element created (the one you suggested to add) was not used in the loop. So I tried nesting a loop within that loop to use your idea. But it's still doing the same thing.

Comment: I changed my code above to show what I tried.

Comment: apologies, I somehow modified your answer!

Comment: I see :) I rejected your edit

Comment: LOL! I just changed my initial post

Comment: not sure if you are still interested. I figured that the problem with this code is that once the loop goes through its first iteration, the next row of images on the webpage is not visible in the viewport, therefore the request becomes stale. I've been trying to make the browser scroll a bit and then "renew" the viewport while staying in the loop. I thought maybe using a while statement but I'm not sure how. Renewing the viewport is relatively easy I think using something like this 
`pyautogui.press("down", presses=13)
 driver.set_window_size(1980, 1068)`

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts with me. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with `pyautogui`. As about setting the window size I'd suggest to use commonly used dimensions like `1920, 1080`